# cannot borrow `element_childre` as mutable more than once at a time `element_childre` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, bevy

I have this code. children are from Bevy query.

```
let mut array_of_elements = vec![];

                    for &child in children.iter() {
                        let result_element = element_children.get_mut(child);

                        if let Ok(element) = result_element {
                            array_of_elements.push(element);
                        }
                    }
```

What I need is to get all children to some vector/array type, that can be sent to another function.

Here's the children definition:

```
fn object_interactions(
  ...,
  mut element_children: Query<
    (Option<&mut Text>, Option<&mut Button>, Option<&Interaction>, Entity)
>,
  mut dialog_query: Query<(&mut Style, &mut Children), With<Dialog>>,
...) {
  for (mut style, children) in dialog_query.iter_mut() {

     let mut array_of_elements = vec![];

                    for &child in children.iter() {
                        let result_element = element_children.get_mut(child);

                        if let Ok(element) = result_element {
                            array_of_elements.push(element);
                        }
                    }

  }

}
```

On children_element I get this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `element_children` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/main.rs:167:50
    |
167 | ...                   let result_element = element_children.get_mut(child);
    |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `element_children` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
...
170 | ...                       array_of_elements.push(element);
    |                           ------------------------------- first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
```

I see that I kinda cannot use children_element twice, but I cannot make a copy or clone element_children as it doesn't have a copy or clone trait.